# pip failed with error code 1 while installing pyzmail

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyzmail

I'm trying to send Gmail through python3. I can use the `email` and `smptlib`, but I wanted to try out `pyzmail`.

However, when I try to install pyzmail, I get this:

```
$ pip3 install pyzmail
Collecting pyzmail
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/9a/c8709821fa15cec44f825fba884284b261a06d8a0033a16f4c35470eb26a/pyzmail-1.0.3.tar.gz
Collecting distribute (from pyzmail)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/ad/1fde06877a8d7d5c9b60eff7de2d452f639916ae1d48f0b8f97bf97e570a/distribute-0.7.3.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.install import install
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from setuptools.command import install_scripts
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
  File "/private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8r/50c4fq6j70q0qmhvwxvr00fw0000gn/T/pip-install-v4ervkb7/distribute/
```

I tested installing a different pip module but everything seemed to be in order.

I also tried `easy_install` but it installed for python 2.7, and not 3.

I think it might be something about my setuptools, but I don't know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pyzmail` packages seems to be inactive now as the [last commit](https://github.com/aspineux/pyzmail/commits/master) and the [last release](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmail/#history) were made 4 years ago. It does not seem to be updated for Python 3.6+.

There was an issue posted on the package's github page with the same error as yours: https://github.com/aspineux/pyzmail/issues/15. Someone posted a patch as a workaround but the best solution is to use `pyzmail36` instead:

> Tagging @cfenollosa @GheloAce in case you're still using this library
>   and are looking for a more maintainable way forward.
>
> This repository unfortunately seems inactive, so I created a new
>   package on PyPI that includes all the [fixes](https://github.com/ascoderu/pyzmail/commit/8b7350684d6d3393f4066ad624fb9180b0e8f2f2) to make pyzmail
>   pip-installable on Python 3.6.
>
> The name of the new package is [pyzmail36](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmail36). You can just update your
>   requirements.txt file to list pyzmail36 instead of pyzmail and all of
>   the rest of your code shouldn't need to change.

So just try with:

```
pip3 install pyzmail36
```

Comment: don't forget to `pip install setuptools==58.0.0` before running `pip3 install pyzmail`, as explained [here](https://github.com/asweigart/automateboringstuff/issues/6)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install pyzmail such as:

1. Try to use " pip install pyzmail36" by installing Python 3.6 first on your device.
2. Try to update the setup-tools by typing "pip install setuptools==20.1.1" and then install pyzmail.
3. Try to search for easy_install on Python 3.x, I have found several links for that.

Good luck.